# Why Is This Code Giving Me An Error

Tags: python-2.7

```
class Square:
        def empty():
                return
        print "What Is The Length And Width Of Your Square"
        total = raw_input()


        def _init_(self, size):
                self.size = total

        def getArea(self):
                area = self.size * self.size
                return area

mySquare = Square()
Square.getArea()
```

I've tried everything, but I keep getting an error. Sorry, I'm new to Python, but will someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The heck is `def empty` meant to represent?

Comment: It should be `__init__` instead of `_init_`. 

Also, `x * x` can be written as `x**2` (this is not a bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several errors, not only the one mentioned by Paco.

Try this:

```
class Square:
        global total
        def empty():
                return
        print "What Is The Length And Width Of Your Square"
        total = raw_input()

        def __init__(self):
                self.size = int(total)

        def getArea(self):
                area = self.size * self.size
                return area

mySquare = Square()
print mySquare.getArea()
```

Comment: anto's answer below is *much* better.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a consideration of the class to get an input from the user to set the size of your square. A better approach would be to move the input outside of the class and simply pass the user entered size as a parameter of your Square constructor (which you already do, but don't use). That way, you could reuse this class.

```
class Square:
    def empty(self):
        return

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size # <---

    def getArea(self):
        area = self.size * self.size
        return area

size = raw_input("What Is The Length And Width Of Your Square? ") # <---
mySquare = Square(size)
mySquare.getArea()
```

Comment: File "area_of_a_square.py", line 13, in <module>
    mySquare = Square(size)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Comment: @Sunny My bad, the correct definition for a constructor in Python is `def __init__(self, ...)` (note the 2 underscores). So, it should be `def __init__(self, size):`.

Answer (score 0):

Call the instance method getArea:

```
mySquare.getArea()
```

instead of

```
Square.getArea()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mySquare = Square(4)
mySquare.getArea()
```

Instead of what you have written and see if it helps.